# go channel, seems all right, but it gets deadlock

Tags: go, synchronization, channel

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
     c := make(chan int)
     c <- 42    // write to a channel

     val := <-c // read from a channel
     println(val)
}
```

I think `c <- 42`   put 42 to channel c, then  `val := <-c` put value in c to val.
but why does it get deadlock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created an unbuffered channel.  So the statement `c <- 42` will block until some other goroutine tries to receive a value from the channel.  Since no other goroutine is around to do this, you got a deadlock.  There are two ways you could fix this:

1. Perform the receive in a different goroutine.
2. Add a buffer to the channel.  For example, `c := make(chan int, 1)` would allow you to send a single value on the channel without blocking.